# How to install apache on ubuntu linux?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, installation

I want to run an Apache server on my Ubuntu box but it doesn't seem to be preinstalled. How can I install the Apache Web Server on Ubuntu Linux?

EDIT:

I apologize folks. I am new to StackExchange. With all due respect why is my question being downvoted?

Comment: I did not down vote this, but a couple things come to mind. It is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. S.O. is geared towards specific programming questions like "I have code `x` and am getting error `y`". Also, the question is a little too broad and does not tell us what you have already tried. Best to do a search and find a tutorial and give it a go first. (A quick search on *install apache on ubuntu* - which you should always do before posting - suggests it should be pretty easy). Then post if you run and into a *specific* problem, possibly on serverfault.

Comment: Hi Leigh, thank you for responding.

I understand most of what you said, except the part about serverfault. Do you mean SO is more for programming while this is more of a SF question because it pertains to apache?

Sorry for the inconvenience... I know i'll get the hang of it :)

Comment: Well I am less familiar with other [stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com/) sites. But suffice it to say they each have a different focus. Stack Overflow's focus is primarily programming questions. So questions about s/w or h/w installation are more likely to be directed elsewhere. Though on any of the sites, you will get *much* better responses (and less down votes) if you demonstrate you have made a sincere effort first before posting. Honestly, a five second search on google yielded the answer on this one, so consider the response below a one-time introductory freebie ;-) ..

Comment: Keep in mind, some questions could go either way. In this case, I suspect the down vote had more to do with "does not show research effort" than anything else. (If you mouse over the down arrow on any post, you will see it in the list of reasons). Do not take it personally. The nice thing about S.O. is you can always edit a post to improve it, and folks often reverse down votes (BTW, Welcome to S.O.! :)

Comment: Thanks Leigh! I will do more research in the future before posting and keep in mind the different sections. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Apache2 on ubuntu

Open a terminal prompt enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to work. Now I just need to configure it :P